# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keeping getting this message on my console log for chrome only:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

It works well on Firefox.

I did some research and it says that *Chrome doesn't support named parameters*. But I don't have any named parameters on line # 131 where it found the error.

Below is the code I am using. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
 var id = checkbox_element.attr('id');
 var recurring_cycle_dropdown = $("#recurring_cycle");
 var label = $("label#" + id);

 //Display the radio options pricing method when the payment  type checkbox has been checked
 if (checkbox_element.is(":checked")) {
     /*If the checkbox id is recurring show the  recurring cycle right
      * after the label next to the radio button, */
     if(id == "recurring"){
         label.after(recurring_cycle_dropdown.show(0, function(){
             //The $(this) is referring to the  recurring_cycle_dropdown
             //not the checkbox
             $(this).css("display","block");

             //****THIS IS THE LINE WHERE THE ERROR IS FOUND****
             $(this).prop("disabled",false);
         }));
     }
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems. (`id` is supposed to be unique, so your label and checkbox shouldn't be using the same id as each other, but that shouldn't matter for the code shown.)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are using default parameters in your code. Javascript does not allow that, but somehow Firefox overrules it.

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was. One of the functions (not in the code I provided) Had a default value in on the params. I removed the default and the code now works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I gave the same solution. You can mark it as answer if it helped you.